# gsutil upload single file and create its parents

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud, gsutil

Using gsutil in a script a need to upload a file and create all its parents.

Here the (ugly) only solution I found

```
 gsutil cp -r ./p0/p1/p2/my_file  gs://my_bucket/p0/p1/p2
```

I'm looking for

```
gsutil cp -? ./p0/p1/p2/my_file  gs://my_bucket/
```

To have /p0/p1/p2 structur created in gs bucket.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. Can you give an example command using the unix `cp` command that you're trying to emulate with gsutil?

Comment: I want to emulate the ‘--parents’ option of cp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gsutil cp /path/to/my_file gs://foo/bar/my_file` should do what you're looking for.

Comment: it's that i'm trying to avoid :)

Comment: How about `file=foo/bar/baz; echo gsutil cp $file gs://bucket/$file` if you really don't want to type `foo/bar` twice? There is no equivalent flag in gsutil.

Comment: It's seems that is the only way. Thanks